# Example of Self-Homeomorphism form 2-sphere which does not have fixed poiny

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

First of all I have not studied yet topology.But I have course of Complex analysis In which I have done conformal mapping .

Form that I can construct map form disc to disc such that no fixed point

Please can any one help me to construct example for 2-sphere.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How about the antipodal map?

Comment: Ohh that nice..But Sir If we consider ball then it that map have fixed as origin. Sir can you suggest me ?

Comment: Each continuous map $f : D^n \to D^n$, where $D^n$ is a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, has a fixed point. This is the **Brouwer fixed point theorem**. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem.

Comment: It's not clear if you're asking about maps of spheres, disks, or extensions from sphere to disk.